# ubuntu + lua in intelliJ : access denied

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, permissions

Here is a screenshot of my error:

[image: here]

I think I was something wrong with my intellij installation, since I can't install plugins from the "browse plugins repository" window : no plugin appears.
I know fundamentals of rights in ubuntu but all files have "lowley" as owner, not "root".
To install intelliJ I got the .tar.gz from their site, unzipped it (as "lowley") in a subdirectory of "home", and the projects files are in a "home" subdir.
Please note that I installed java 9 in /opt/java/jdk9, which owner is "lowley".

Here is a screenshot taken from the terminal:

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

done : chmod 777 -R lua02emmy (the directory)